# Binding MouseClick to widget of an instance

Tags: python, binding, tkinter

I have an instance of a [ttkcalendar](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/pep-0384/Demo/tkinter/ttk/ttkcalendar.py) object, "cal".  When I bind a button click to cal, the function called only executes if I click in the corners of the ttcalendar frame; when I click on the actual calendar area, while the ttkcalendar functions execute, my bind does not.

This code runs when I click Frame corners

```
# Calendar Frame
    self.cal=Calendar(LeftFrame)
    self.cal.pack(side=TOP)
    self.cal.bind("<Button-1>",self.clicked)
```

I thought that if I try to bind to the canvas object of the calendar it would work.  However this code returns AttributeError: Calendar instance has no attribute canvas.

```
# Calendar Frame
    self.cal=Calendar(LeftFrame)
    self.cal.pack(side=TOP)
    self.cal.canvas.bind("<Button-1>",self.clicked)
```

As I said, internal ttkcalendar binds work fine for switching date shown.  Any insights? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error message should be pretty clear. If python is telling you "`AttributeError: Calendar instance has no attribute canvas`", you must assume that to be true.

Looking at the source code of the `Calendar` class, I don't see any `canvas` attribute. Just like the error is telling you, you're trying to access an attribute that doesn't exist.

The `Calendar` class *does* have an attribute named `_canvas`, maybe you can try using that instead. Though, that leading underscore denotes that it is intended as a private attribute and may go away in future revisions of the code.

Comment: Hi, I did try that as well to no avail.. Is there any way to get the click event to register both on the widget as well as the frame in which it is held?

Comment: @user3883010: I don't quite understand what you're asking. You can certainly make the same binding on more than one widget. Just bind to the listbox, and make the same binding on the frame. There are other techniques as well, but it really depends on what your goal is.  Search this site for "bindtags" to see some other more advanced binding techniques.

Comment: I have the calendar widget instance, which displays a calendar.  If you click on it, it will highlight the selected date.  It seems that the only public function is selection, which returns the datename of the currently selected date.  What I want is to have the code containing this calendar instance also have a bind so that when the click on the calendar happens, I can call another function in that code.  As I have it, the click only runs the internal events of calendar instance, but not the exterior function of its container.